# Are there any reserved identifiers (e.g. starting with underscore) in Rust apart from keywords?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer

In C++, [certain identifiers starting with underscores are reserved to be used by the compiler or the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Are there similar rules for identifiers in Rust? Of course, keywords (like `if`) are not allowed as an identifier, but apart from that: may I use any identifier I want?

Comment: Well, at least starting with one underscore seems common practice for unused arguments. The prelude and lack of text-based macros may help considerably in cutting down the number of reserved identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/identifiers.html), identifiers may start with an underscore and there don't seem to be restrictions other than the length (not just an underscore) and keywords:

> An identifier is any nonempty Unicode (see note) string of the following form:
>
> Either
>
> - The first character has property [XID_start](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AXID_Start%3A%5D&abb=on&g=&i=)
> - The remaining characters have property [XID_continue](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AXID_Continue%3A%5D&abb=on&g=&i=)
>
> Or
>
> - **The first character is _**
> - The identifier is more than one character, _ alone is not an identifier
> - The remaining characters have property [XID_continue](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AXID_Continue%3A%5D&abb=on&g=&i=)
>
> that does not occur in the set of [keywords](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/grammar.html#keywords).
>
> note: Non-ASCII characters in identifiers are currently feature gated.

XID_start and XID_continue are [properties](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp) of Unicode [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point); digits, for example (and most notably), do not have the XID_start property and are thus not valid as first characters of identifiers.